# find the source of the error - Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to find the source of my problem. I keep getting this error. I tried debugging the widgets but just can't find the root of the problem. The debugger or widget inspector doesn't tell me where to look into, Would be great if i could get some help.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Padding widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  Column ← Expanded ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Positioned ← Stack ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5723
```

Here, is the widget tree that seems to be causing the problem but I can't figure out which part?

```
Positioned(
    left: 0.0,
    right: 0.0,
    bottom: 0.0,
    child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
            boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black38,
                    blurRadius: 16.0,
                    spreadRadius: 0.5,
                    offset: Offset(0.7, 0.7))
            ],
        ),
        height: 270.0,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 18.0),
            child: Expanded(
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                        Text(
                            arrivalDropText + durationRide,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 17.0,
                                fontFamily: "Brand-Bold",
                                color: Colors.deepPurple),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            height: 6.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                                Text(
                                    widget.rideDetails.rider_name,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: "Brand-Bold", fontSize: 24.0),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                                    child: Icon(Icons.phone),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            height: 22.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                            children: [
                                Image.asset(
                                    "images/images/pickicon.png",
                                    height: 16.0,
                                    width: 16.0,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                    width: 18.0,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                        child: Text(
                                            widget.rideDetails.pickup_address,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            height: 16.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                            children: [
                                Image.asset(
                                    "images/images/desticon.png",
                                    height: 16.0,
                                    width: 16.0,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                    width: 18.0,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                        child: Text(
                                            widget.rideDetails.dropoff_address,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            height: 22.0,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                            child: RaisedButton(
                                onPressed: () async {

                                },
                                color: btnClr,
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                            Text(
                                                btnTitle,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                            Icon(
                                                Icons.directions_car,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                size: 26.0,
                                            )
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        )
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the first `Expanded` widget because it is inside the `Padding` widget. The exception clearly says that `The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Padding widget`, so you need to put Expanded outside of Padding.
Change this:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 18.0),
  child: Expanded(
    child: Column(
      ...
```

to this:

```
Expanded(
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 18.0),
    child: Column(
      ...
```

Comment: Thanx but it didn't resolve the issue, However as per your suggestion and @pskink I removed it .